# Manipulate position of an HTML element in angular 2

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angular, angular2-template, typescript2.0

I have an angular component template like this.

```
<my-app>
  <nav id="nav-bar">
    <ul>
     <li id="item-1"></li>
     <li>
        <div id="item-2"></div>
     </li>
     <li id="item-3"></li>

  <div id="middle-div">

  </div>
  <div id="side-div">

  </div>

</nav>
</my-app>
```

Now here I want to take the div with id, 'item-2' and append it to nav-bar so that it appears below the div with id "side-div".
I can easily do this with javascript's appendChild function like this.

```
var item = document.getElementById("item-2");
var nav = document.getElementById("nav-bar");
//change position of searchform in DOM
nav.appendChild(item);
```

However, I want to be able to do this in component's typescript file. Is ElementRef an ideal solution to this? or is there any other way to achieve this?

the component looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: '/app/Templates/nav.html',
providers: [MyService]
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(){
  }

  ngOnInit(){
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) using [ElementRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html). Here is an example

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button type="button" (click)="appendToChild()">Append Item to Child</button>

      <div #item>Item</div>

      <div #appendToChildEl></div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class App {

  @ViewChild('item') item: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('appendToChildEl') appendToChildEl: ElementRef;


  appendToChild() {
    this.appendToChildEl.nativeElement.appendChild(this.item.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

A plunker example:
https://embed.plnkr.co/7DJ1nWN6sl563hcR71FV/

Comment: This solution works for me. Looks simple and serves the exact purpose I wished for.

Answer (score -1):

You could also do something like this if you don't want to use ElementRef

User a service or component variable to control the position:

```
<my-app>
  <nav id="nav-bar">
    <ul>
     <li id="item-1"></li>
     <li>
        <div id="item-2" *ngIf="defaultPos"></div>
     </li>
     <li id="item-3"></li>

  <div id="middle-div">

  </div>
  <div id="side-div">

  </div>
  <div id="item-2" *ngIf="newPos"></div>
</nav>
</my-app>
```

Comment: This did cross my mind but I didn't want to create two same elements. Thanks anyway.